# Is it possible to get Access to Send Email (All Email Services) property in Deliverability

Tags: permissions, properties

I try to get Send Email (All Email Services) property by ant and get metadate. But i really dont know where can i find this property. Can you give me hint what should i include in my package.xml
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Deliverability settings cannot be access via Apex or API.  Kindly review Idea link [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cHBEAA2).  Also, there is a workaround mentioned in above Idea link please review.

Thanks